# Get the value of an xsi:type attribute in ActionScript 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have a little bit of XML that looks like this:

```
<LayerDefinition xsi:type ="GridLayerDefinition">
  <Name>Solids</Name>
  <Grid>
    <Width>48</Width>
    <Height>48</Height>
  </Grid>
  <ScrollFactor>
    <X>1</X>
    <Y>1</Y>
  </ScrollFactor>
  <Color A="255" R="0" G="0" B="0" />
  <ExportMode>Rectangles</ExportMode>
</LayerDefinition>
```

I want to get the value of that xsi:type attribute. Because of the colon, I can't simply use the .@whatever. It won't compile. I was advised to try and use .attribute("xsi:type"), but that returns nothing. Here's my code as stands:

```
private function loadProject():void
    {
        var curProject:XML = FP.getXML(TESTPROJECT);
        var entry:XML;
        var counter:uint = 0;
        trace("Loading project");
    //  trace(curProject.*);
        trace (curProject.LayerDefinitions.LayerDefinition.attribute("xsi:type"));
        for each (entry in curProject.LayerDefinitions.LayerDefinition)
        {
            //trace("Grid type is: " + entry.attribute("xsi:type"));
            //  trace("Grid type is: " + entry.attribute('xsi:type'));
            //  trace ("Grid is: " + entry.Name);
        }
    }
```

Any advice? I feel like I've tried everything at this point

Comment: The sample xml you posted is not standard e4x format. Because of that you can not parse it. ROOT nodes are not accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't reply to my comment on your other post, why not?  Where is xsi defined? somewhere in your code that uses this XML there should be a xmlns:xsi="someuri".  I've run into similar issues with attributes in XML that have an xml namespace, for E4X in AS3 to pull these qualified attributes or nodes I had to create a Namespace in AS3.

Read the section called XML Namespaces in the document below

http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=4

basically you need to do something like (below taken from link above):

```
// XML with xpl namespace
var xml:XML = 
    <xml xmlns:xpl="http://www.example.com/uri/">
        <xpl:text value="Hello World" xpl:value="Hello Namespace" />
    </xml>;

// Define namespace with xpl URI
var xplNs:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.example.com/uri/");

// Get value of text attribute
// with and without namespace
trace(xml.xplNs::text.@value); // traces Hello World
trace(xml.xplNs::text.@xplNs::value); // traces Hello Namespace
```

Another option is:

```
var xplNs:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.example.com/uri/");
use namespace xmplNs;
```

In your case the argument for the new Namespace call should be whatever xmlns:xsi= is set to.  Then you prefix any attribute or node you want to fetch using that namespace with xplNs:: or whatever you named your Namespace instance.

Alternatively if you're alright with a more hacky approach you could follow advice on this site as well to just remove the namespaces (Admittedly I've done this myself before but always felt it was a dirty workaround for something I could do correctly) http://brianmriley.wordpress.com/2008/03/14/remove-xml-namespaces-in-flex-or-as3/

If no where in the code there's a xmlns:xsi I'm at a loss for what's going on.

Comment: Got it: trace(curProject.LayerDefinitions.LayerDefinition.@nSpace::type);

Thanks a ton!